# VB.Net Adding predefined dictionaries to LibraryWithMedia

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm creating an application where I have different libraries, books and non-book media stored in dictionaries and displayed in listboxes. The user can add and remove additional dictionaries for any of these elements.

I have a listbox for "Books at Current library" and "Non-Book Media at Current Library" Which will display the media that is linked to the specific library that is highlighted in the listbox. And the user can freely add and remove different media to the library.

I'm having issues adding predefined associations together on `frmAssociationScreen`. I want to hardcode a few associations to `LibraryWithMedia` Where "Zahnow Library" will have Keys: 101 and 104 which are displayed in the "Books at Current Library" listbox before adding any from `lstAllBooks`.

Screenshots of the two forms:

frmManager: https://prnt.sc/mnd8qf

frmAssociationScreen: https://prnt.sc/mnd8sh

The three ways I've tried to implement but failed on `frm_Load`

```
    frmManager.LibraryWithMedia("Zahnow Library").dicBooks.Add("101", "Zen and the Art of Appliance Wiring")
    frmManager.EquippedLibrary(lstAllLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Add("104", "Data Structures for Fun and Profit")

    tmp = New frmManager.LibraryWithMedia(frmManager.Libraries.Keys(0))
    tmp.dicBooks.Add("101", "Zen and the Art of Appliance Wiring")
```

Sub `frmAssociationScreen_Load`

```
Private Sub frmAssociationScreen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim tmp As frmManager.LibraryWithMedia

    lstAllLibraries.Items.Clear()

    For Each library In frmManager.Libraries
        lstAllLibraries.Items.Add(library.Value & " --- " & library.Key)
    Next

    For Each book In frmManager.Books
        lstAllBooks.Items.Add(book.Value & " --- " & book.Key)
    Next

    For Each nonBook In frmManager.nonBookMedia
        lstAllMedia.Items.Add(nonBook.Value & " --- " & nonBook.Key)
    Next

    ' The code i'm struggling to implement
    ' Three different ways I've tried to implement it
    ' construct equipped library and define the library names
    frmManager.EquippedLibrary = New List(Of frmManager.LibraryWithMedia)
    frmManager.LibraryWithMedia("Zahnow Library").dicBooks.Add("101", "Zen and the Art of Appliance Wiring")
    frmManager.EquippedLibrary(lstAllLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Add("104", "Data Structures for Fun and Profit")

    tmp = New frmManager.LibraryWithMedia(frmManager.Libraries.Keys(0))
    tmp.dicBooks.Add("101", "Zen and the Art of Appliance Wiring")

    ' initialise each library with book/media dictionary
    populateEquippedLibNames()

End Sub
```

frmManager:

```
Public Class frmManager

    Public Libraries As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Books As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public nonBookMedia As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Public EquippedLibrary As New List(Of LibraryWithMedia)

    Structure LibraryWithMedia

        Dim strLibraryName As String
        Dim dicBooks As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim nonBookMedia As Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Sub New(ByVal LibName As String)

            strLibraryName = LibName
            dicBooks = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            nonBookMedia = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        End Sub

    End Structure

    Private Sub frmManager_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Libraries.Add("SVSU", "Zahnow Library")
        Libraries.Add("BR", "Fleschner Memorial Library")
        Libraries.Add("SDJ", "Scott D. James Technical Repository")

        Books.Add("104", "Data Structures for Fun and Profit")
        Books.Add("103", "Doing More With Less - Naval Lint Art")
        Books.Add("102", "Interpretive Klingon Poetry")
        Books.Add("105", "Programming with the Bidgoli")
        Books.Add("101", "Zen and the Art of Appliance Wiring")

        nonBookMedia.Add("201", "CD - IEEE Computer: the Hits")
        nonBookMedia.Add("203", "DVD - Databases and You: the Video Experience")
        nonBookMedia.Add("202", "DVD - The Pirates of Silicon Valley")

        populatelstLibrary()
        populatelstBooks()
        populatelstBookMedia()

    End Sub
```

frmAssociationScreen:

```
Public Class frmAssociationScreen

    Sub populateEquippedLibNames()

        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim tmpSingleLib As frmManager.LibraryWithMedia

        For counter = 0 To frmManager.Libraries.Count - 1
            tmpSingleLib = New frmManager.LibraryWithMedia(frmManager.Libraries.Values(counter))
            frmManager.EquippedLibrary.Add(tmpSingleLib)
            tmpSingleLib = Nothing
        Next

    End Sub
```

populateLstLibrary()

```
Sub populatelstLibrary()

    lstLibraries.Items.Clear()

    For Each library In Libraries
        lstLibraries.Items.Add(library.Value & " --- " & library.Key)
    Next

End Sub
```

populatelstBooks()

```
Sub populatelstBooks()

    lstBooks.Items.Clear()

    For Each book In Books
        lstBooks.Items.Add(book.Value & " --- " & book.Key)
    Next

End Sub
```

populatelstBookMedia()

```
Sub populatelstBookMedia()

    lstBookMedia.Items.Clear()

    For Each bookMedia In nonBookMedia
        lstBookMedia.Items.Add(bookMedia.Value & " --- " & bookMedia.Key)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when using the methods above?

Comment: When using the `tmp` variable  and `frmManager.EquippedLibrary` to try and add them, I do not get errors, just no output. `frmManager.LibraryWithMedia` Gives the error: `... is a structure type and cannot be used as an expression`

Comment: Those are under `frm_Load` for the three way's I've tried to implement.

Comment: Can you post the code in these three subs `populatelstLibrary()
        populatelstBooks()
        populatelstBookMedia()`

Comment: Updated, however those are used to populate on the first form. My issue is on the second form. @preciousbetine

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
For Each library As frmManager.LibraryWithMedia In frmManager.EquippedLibrary
    If library.strLibraryName = "Zahnow Library" Then
        library.dicBooks.Add("101", "Zen and the Art of Appliance Wiring")
    End If
Next
```

Or to select the items from the listbox, use

```
For Each library As frmManager.LibraryWithMedia In frmManager.EquippedLibrary
    If library.strLibraryName =  lstAllLibraries.Text Then
        library.dicBooks.Add("101", "Zen and the Art of Appliance Wiring")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What would I use instead of `lib` as that errors out as `expression expected`. Would I use `lstAllLibraries`? Because that has 0 output as well.

Comment: I tried to create a variable `tmpLib As frmManager.LibraryWithMedia` and use that instead, which removes the error but 0 output.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that lib was a keyword in vb.

Comment: Right, even as a variable or doing it the same way in your updated version I'm still getting 0 output for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean by zero output?

Comment: The `Books at Current Library` listbox remains empty. And I know it's not being added due to no exception occurring when trying to add it,  as it should be a duplicate.